# Check in cabin bag at Dublin Airport with Aer Lingus

Tags: hand-luggage, check-in, dublin, dub, aer-lingus

Last time I flew from Dublin Airport with Aer Lingus in August 2019, they sent me a text saying that if I wanted, I could pay **€5** and check-in my cabin bag.

Do they still offer this?  I would like to avail of this option again.  I can't see anything mentioned on the website.  I don't know if this is something they routinely offered, or only under specific conditions (e.g. fully booked flights where there might not be room for everyone's cabin baggage).

This is the wording of the text, which I received approximately 15 hours before departure:

> Dear Guest, we invite you to start your journey stress free and take
>   advantage of cabin baggage check-in for EUR5.00 by credit or debit
>   card at Dublin Airport.  We hope this offer will make your experience
>   in the airport easier as you'll save time and avoid the stress of
>   unpacking and repacking at security. Simply go to Desk 32 at Dublin
>   Airport with your boarding pass, check in your cabin bag for EUR5.00,
>   proceed through security to your boarding gate and collect your bag at
>   your destination. Your Ref:XXXXXX

Comment: I took a couple of flights on Aer Lingus from DUB in November.  I didn't get any such texts.  It's possible that such an option might have been offered at check in, but I don't recall.

Comment: I believe most airlines offering this (either in advance, or at check-in time, or even at the gate before boarding starts) for a reduced fee or even for free will do so only when the flight is fully booked and people are more likely to have lots of hand luggage. They wouldn’t want to miss the opportunity to charge the full price of a check-in bag if you want to do so anyway. I believe some airlines do it year-round (with a much lower weight/size limit than regular check-in bags) but this is quite an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things have changed, so this answer is an update.

Not only can you check in your hand baggage, this is actually required now unless you pay an additional fee.  At Dublin airport, simply use the self check-in kiosks, then proceed to the rapid bag drop with your case.  N.B. the kiosks weigh your bags and are less forgiving than a human, if it weighs 10.1 Kg, you will have to take something out.

At other airports where Aer Lingus does not have a presence simply proceed to the check-in desk.